# Deploy WAR to WSO2 AS using maven?

Tags: wso2

How do I get maven (POM) to deploy standard WAR artifacts to a WSO2 Application Server?
Please don't tell me how to do it with the Developer Studio, I want to be able to automate this.

I'm also interested to hear from anyone who has information about production deployment workflows using puppet/chef and maven (with WSO2 in mind, of course).

Regards,
Matt